# Watin is not populating Input fields nor button getting clicked when running on server in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, watin, windows-server

When using Watin in a mvc 5 asp.net application to fetch data from a https website, the code runs locally on IIS but when deployed on server it seems that the button does not get clicked. I can see in the body html and all the input boxes but no data is populated in them as well. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors on the page when it is deployed to the server?

Comment: Provide more context, your question is very vague and generic. Providing better information will allow us to help you.